# Moq, setup a Stub and Expected result

Tags: moq

I am creating a mock and a stub.
The stub is the following contract:

```
public interface IMailService
{
   void SetCredentials(ICredentials credentials);
   bool Connect();
}
```

My assert is the following:
"Passing the right credentials to IMailService, will connect succesfully".
So I have created my mock object:

```
var mockAdapter = new Mock<IMailService>();
```

Now I should prepare this adapter. If the SetCredentials method is called using the right credentials, then the Connect() method should return true. Otherwise it will return false.

I am just not sure how I can setup this behavior using Moq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 tests to cover this, one in which `Connect` returns `true` and one in which it returns `false`.

```
[Fact] // or [Test] depending on your testing framework
public void MailServiceConnectsIfCredentialsAreValid()
{
    var mockMailService = new Mock<IMailService>();
    mockMailService.Setup(x => x.Connect()).Returns(true);

    // The rest of your code which will use the mockMailService.Object...
}

[Fact]
public void MailServiceFailsToConnectIfCredentialsAreInvalid()
{
    var mockMailService = new Mock<IMailService>();
    mockMailService.Setup(x => x.Connect()).Returns(false);

    // The rest of your code which will use the mockMailService.Object...
}
```

For the purpose of your test, you do not care what `ICredentials` are passed. You are just covering the 2 possibilities of `IMailService.Connect()` which are it returns `true` or `false`. The actual logic for determining which will happen will exist in your tests for the actual implementation of `IMailService`.

You could also potentially scrap the `SetCredentials` method and just pass the `ICredentials` to `Connect`.

```
bool Connect(ICredentials credentials);
```

Comment: Interesting, this will provide some refactoring to my code. So in this case I should validate the ICredentials within the connect method. Thanks!